# What is each ore worth

Tags: pocket-mine

I have been playing pocket mine and I have noticed the ores don't seem to have a logical order in value e.g. Iron is more valuable than gold. So I have been wondering, what is the value of each ore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base value for each mineral is:

- Coal (black) = 1
- Gold (gold) = 2
- Iron (white) = 3
- Diamond (light blue) = 5
- Emerald (green) = 7
- Sapphire (dark blue) = 9
- Spinel (pink) = 11
- Topaz (orange) = 13

This can be altered by certain cards or the Greedy Goblin.

([source](http://pocketmine.wikia.com/wiki/Minerals))